# how to get last string '22' using java

Tags: java, string

this is my code :

```
 public class a {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "12345aaaa##22";
        String b = a[-2:];
        System.out.println(b);
      } 
}
```

how to get last string '22'   using java

thanks

Comment: Define "last string '22'": do you want "the last two characters" or "the last instance of '22' anywhere in that string" or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your requirement.

If you need the last two chars from a given String, use `substring`:

```
String lastToChars = input.substring(input.length()-2);
// if you need that number as integer
int value = Integer.parseInt(lastToChars);
```

If you need everything *after* `##` (may be a delimiter), do a:

```
String charsAfterDelimiter = input.split("##")[1];
```

Comment: So we still don't know exactly what he wanted ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**Some seemingly relevant String methods:**

[`String.substring(start, end)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%2C%20int%29) (or [`String.substring(start)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)):

> Returns a new string that is a
>   substring of this string. The
>   substring begins at the specified
>   `beginIndex` and extends to the
>   character at index `endIndex - 1`. Thus
>   the length of the substring is
>   `endIndex-beginIndex`.

[`String.lastIndexOf(str)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> Returns the index within this string
>   of the rightmost occurrence of the
>   specified substring. The rightmost
>   empty string `""` is considered to occur
>   at the index value `this.length()`. The
>   returned index is the largest value k
>   such that  `this.startsWith(str, k)`

---

**Answering the Question:**

You question wasn't that clear, but if I understand you right and you want the last two characters as String, you can do this:

```
String a = "12345aaaa##22";
System.out.println(a.substring(a.length() - 2));
```

**Output:**

> 22

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `String.lastIndexOf(String)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression if you are trying to retrieve the "last number" of a string.

Something like "([0-9]+)$", for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
String a = "12345aaaa##22";
int value = Integer.ParseInt(a.substring(a.length() - 2);
System.out.println(value);
```

or if you don't know 22 position you shoud use this

```
String a = "12345aaaa##22";
String number = "22";
int position = a.SlastIndexOf("22");
int value = Integer.ParseInt(position+number.lenght());
System.out.println(value);
```